# CSS style won't applied on the page after style update

Tags: css

well i update my width size:

```
#content_area{
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 650px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}
```

with this  :

```
 #content_area{
    height:500px;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: 31px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}
```

but on the page it didn't apply the the change. how did i know u asked? well the page didn't change its width and i also looked at Firefox developer>inspector>style editor and its the same as the previous with size. i need help! thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Maybe you didn't save your changes or try after clearing the cache or refresh the page.

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` or use Private Browsing or Incognito Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with Cache not getting cleared. A few pointers that devs could have in handy are:

1. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Clearing browser cache, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>.
3. Using **Incognito** or **Private Browsing** mode (usually available in latest browsers). (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for Firefox and Internet Explorer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for Chrome).

Another way to include the updated CSS is to embed something with its URL like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?version=1" />
```

Where the `1` is an arbitrary number, could include anything after the `?`. This will force the browser to request the server for a new and updated file, instead of serving from already existing file in the cache.

The ultimate final stuff is to do either of these two:

1. Try a different browser.
2. Try a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to do a hard refresh: Ctrl + F5
2. Try clearing your cache on the browser settings.
3. Try opening the site in incognito mode on chrome. Ctrl+Shift+N